# Moving Files to Folder Based on Filename

Tags: powershell

I have several thousand files in a single directory. Many of these files need to be grouped together in their own directory based off a part of the filename. I need a part of the filename to be the destination folder name. I put dashes around the part of the filename I need the directory to be named.

For instance, the following files are located in a single directory:

- filea-123-.PDF
- fileb-123-.PDF
- filec-456-.PDF
- filed-123-.PDF
- file3-456-.PDF

I need all files with "-123-" to be moved to a folder called "123". Likewise, I need all files with "-456-" to be moved to a folder called "456" and so on.

Here is what I have so far:

```
$dir = "C:\convert"
$filelist = (Get-Item $dir).GetFiles()
foreach ($file in $filelist)
{
    $newdir = $file.Name -match '-\d+-'
    Move-Item $file -Destination "C:\convert\$matches[0]"
}
```

I've also tried this:

```
$dir = "C:\convert"
$filelist = (Get-Item $dir).GetFiles()
foreach ($file in $filelist)
{
    $pieces = $file-split"-"
    $start = $pieces.Count*-1
    $folder = $pieces[$Start..-2]-join" "
    $destination = "C:\convert\{0}" -f $folder

    if (Test-Path $destination -PathType Container)
    {
        Move-Item -Path $filename -Destination $destination
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site, could you demonstrate what code you have attempted so far? Currently this just looks like a code request which this site is not a provider for. See the following site on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Sure. Below are a few examples of what I have tried so far that have netted me errors or empty results. 


`$dir = "C:\convert"
$filelist = (get-item $dir).GetFiles()

foreach ($file in $filelist) 
{
    $newdir = $file.name -match '-\d+-'
    move-item $file -Destination "C:\convert\$matches[0]"
}`

Comment: I've also tried this:
`$dir = "C:\convert"
$filelist = (get-item $dir).GetFiles()

foreach ($file in $filelist) 
{
 $pieces = $file-split"-"
 
 $start = $pieces.Count*-1
 $folder = $pieces[$Start..-2]-join" "

 $destination = "C:\convert\{0}" -f $folder

 if(test-path $destination -pathtype Container)
  {
   move-item -path $filename -Destination $destination
  }
 
 }`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$dir = "C:\convert"

$filelist = @(Get-ChildItem $dir)

ForEach ($file in $filelist){
    # Gets the '123' part
    $folder = $file.Name.Split("-")[1] 

    #Test if folder exists.
    Set-Location ($dir+'\'+$folder)

    #If no folder, create folder.
    if(!$?){ mkdir ($dir+'\'+$folder) }

    #Move item keeping same name.
    Move-Item $file.FullName ($dir+'\'+$folder+'\'+$file.Name) 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a capturing group in your regular expression for extracting the number from the filename:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -File | Where-Object {
  $_.Name -match '-(\d+)-.pdf$'
} | ForEach-Object {
  Move-Item $_.FullName ('{0}\{1}' -f $dir, $matches[1])
}
```

or like this, since `Move-Item` can read directly from the pipeline:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -File | Where-Object {
  $_.Name -match '-(\d+)-.pdf$'
} | Move-Item -Destination {'{0}\{1}' -f $dir, $matches[1]}
```

Answer (score 0):

I like Ansgars approach, If the sub folders still have to be created:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter "*-*-.PDF" | 
  Where-Object Name -match '-(\d+)-.pdf$' | 
  ForEach-Object {
    $DestDir = Join-Path $dir $matches[1]
    If (!(Test-Path $DestDir)) {mkdir $DestDir|Out-Null}
    $_|Move-Item -Destination $DestDir
}
```